# Rails renders my raw data in html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've setup a Rails project:
User->Project->Sample

When I view my Projects as table everything is fine. I render a table template:

```
<%= render 'layouts/projects_table' %>
```

but when I render my samples for a project

```
<%= render 'layouts/samples_table' %>
```

I get the table but before the table I get my raw data rendered:

```
[#<Sample id: 28, name: "abcd", size: 11, quantity: 11.0, created_at: "2013-04-04 09:58:50"> ... ]
```

ProjectsController:

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @samples = @project.samples
end
```

_samples_table:

```
<table id="samples" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Sample Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Size
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantity
        </th>
        <th>


        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <%= @samples.each do |sample| %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= link_to sample.name, project_sample_path(@project, sample) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= sample.size %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= sample.quantity %>
            </td>

            <td>
                <% if !sample.libraries.any?%>
                <%= link_to 'Del', project_sample_path(@project, sample), 
                    :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
                <% end %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Everything else works fine.
Any help would be appreciated!

Oliver

Comment: You need to show us the code in your `samples_table` view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `=` from the loop definition

```
<%= @samples.each do |sample| %>
```

should be

```
<% @samples.each do |sample| %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've totally overseen this...  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're outputting the return value of `.each`.

```
<%= @samples.each do |sample| %>
```

should be

```
<% @samples.each do |sample| %>
```